# How do I change the visible width of an attribute data type in a Visio 2016 crows feet diagram?

Tags: attributes

I have a Visio 2016 crows feet diagram.

I have figured out how to right click on an entity and set *Show Attribute Types*.

I figured out how to click (carefully, it turns out) to highlight a single attribute's data type.

Next, I figured out how to change the default of *int* to something like *DateTime*.

However, no matter how I stretch/resize the entity or the attribute, I cannot seem to make the data type portion of the attribute wider so that the word *DateTime* does not spill over onto two lines.

How do I *visually* widen ***just*** the data type portion of an attribute so that it fits horizontally on one line?

I was hoping that Visio 2016 would allow me to do this with a simple right-click, Properties, but alas, there is no such thing as Properties for an attribute (or if there is, it is cleverly well hidden by Microsoft).